# How can I turn off USB data using code in android?

Tags: android, usb

How can I turn off usb data so that the phone will only charge?

I tried to look for it all over the net but I only found couple of class that deal with usb but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such concept in Android itself.

Some device manufacturers may elect to have "Charge only" versus other modes on their specific devices. You will need to contact those device manufacturers to determine if they expose any sort of API to allow apps to control this.

Comment: It suppose to be an Android option and not the manufacturer of the device.

Comment: @AlexKapustian: You are welcome to believe what you want. I own about 50 Android devices. Only about a half-dozen offer this. None were manufactured more recently than 2010. None are Nexus devices. There are no APIs for this in Android SDK. Of course, you are welcome to create your own ROM mod that offers this capability, but then that will only affect the people who install your ROM mod.

Comment: OK, you could say it from the begining - "There are no APIs for this in Android SDK" with no other info